# Will editing a question push it back onto the top of the stack?

Tags: support, questions

It seems logical that editing the title of a question (or the tags, by adding one) might push the question back on top of the stack, whereas editing the body of a question would not. Is that the expected behaviour? I do not see this documented.

Are there special events that moderators see that other users to do not see, like "recently edited" questions?

I am trying to avoid inadvertently creating more noise by being nitpicky about my question's title or body. Particularly if I want to update it later, silently, just for community value.

Comment: Yup, it will put it to the top of 'active' questions.  Kinda' like a bump, and just like a bump, kinda frowned upon if used like a bump.

Answer (score 5):

Editing a question (title or body) pushes it up to the top of the **Active** stack.  It won't go to the top of the **Newest** stack.  See the different tabs at the top of the [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/) to see what I mean.

Comment: does the same apply for comments to the question itself or ANY other activity on the question?

Comment: New answers put it back on the active stack.  Comments do not.  I don't know about editing answers.

Comment: Editing an answer will bump the question.

Comment: For example, every so often I find something good to add to the accepted answer for this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394

I've noticed that when I do that it gets bumped and gets a few new votes, to the point where it's up to 125.

Comment: Ok, great, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks, that's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a question pushes it up to the top of the active section.

Comment: Can you provide any more insight?